# BOOTCHART : not creating the bootchart after reboot

Tags: boot, 14.04, bootchart

Should not bootchart create the image file after I restarted the system? It is not happening so. WHat should I be doing?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you have the following packages installed on your system:

```
$ dpkg-query -W bootchart pybootchartgui
bootchart   0.90.2-8ubuntu2
pybootchartgui  0+r141-0ubuntu3
```

Then all you have to do to (re)generate a png picture of your boot sequence is to select an archive in `/var/log/bootchart/`, for example:

```
$ cd $HOME
$ bootchart /var/log/bootchart/sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s-trusty-20140915-1.tgz
parsing '/var/log/bootchart/sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s-trusty-20140915-1.tgz'
parsing 'header'
parsing 'proc_stat.log'
parsing 'proc_diskstats.log'
parsing 'proc_ps.log'
warning: no parent for pid '2' with ppid '0'
merged 0 logger processes
pruned 276 process, 0 exploders, 155 threads, and 22 runs
False
bootchart written to 'bootchart.png'
```

But by default `bootchart` saves png in /var/log/bootchart/ too:

[image]

Comment: My /var/log/bootchart directory is empty.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse even after reboot? What's your release?

Comment: Even after reboot. 15.04

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: It's probably a bug, I don't know. You could create a new question to get answers/help for 15.04.

Comment: same problem here: /var/log/bootchart is empty. anybody found a solution for this?

Comment: @codeling: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bootchart/+bug/1458170

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Run Bootchart

After Bootchart is installed, you will need to run it. To be able to properly time the boot sequence, Bootchart needs to be started as one of the first services. For this reason, Bootchart is not started as other services, using the Start scripts. Instead, it is invoked during the boot, by editing the GRUB menu parameters.

This may sound frightening, but it is quite simple and harmless.

First, when the system boots, press Esc to display the GRUB menu, in case it is not showing.

Second, press e to edit the GRUB menu. This pauses the timer and allows you to add your changes to the GRUB menu. Under the highlighted line, which you normally boot, simple type down the following string: init=/sbin/bootchartd.

source: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/bootchart.html

Comment: More info http://www.bootchart.org/docs.html