# Bootchart folder empty after reboot

Tags: 16.04, bootchart

I'm trying to trouble shoot my boot process by using `bootchart`. I installed using `sudo apt-get install bootchart` and rebooted the computer - but, though the folder `/var/log/bootchart` exists, it is empty.

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524262/bootchart-not-creating-the-bootchart-after-reboot) thread that answers a similar question as well as [this bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bootchart/+bug/1458170) that describes exactly my problem, but both posts are over a year old and I thought that I'd give it another try - maybe I have a different underlying problem than the other posters.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Please do not follow guides for older releases. systemd (16.04) has its own bootchart.

Comment: Dupe http://askubuntu.com/a/788886/15811

Comment: @Rinzwind True, that solved it. Question can be closed.